# Menu bar finder scripts always missing

Tags: finder, applescript, mojave, automator, menu-bar

I've added several automator applications to the scripts editor folder and I'd like them to be available at all times in the menu bar dropdown menu.

However they're only available in the Finder Scripts section of the dropdown menu only when the Finder window is open. If I close all finder windows then the Find Scripts section disappears from the drop down menu.

How can I keep my customs applications / scripts visible at all times in the dropdown menu?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @red_menace Thanks a lot, that did the trick! You can set that as the answer :)

Comment: Just a helpful tip for you.  The Script menu in the menubar allows the use of alias files of the original scripts or workflows files.  This is especially valuable because if you delete any of the aliases from the Script menu in the menubar, only the aliases will be deleted, leaving the originals untouched.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to create them as Automator Services (or Quick Actions in macOS Mojave and above).

Doing this will then add them to the Services menu available within all apps. For example, if you created a Service called Duplicate Folder, you coudl run that from the Services list within any Application menu (e.g. Finder > Services, Safari > Services, TextEdit > Services, etc).

**Create a service using Automator**

This is an example of how to create a service in Automator that runs an AppleScript code:

1. Launch Automator (usually found within your Applications folder)
2. Go to File > New
3. Select Service and click Choose (**Note:** in macOS Mojave and above, select the Quick Action option)
4. In the top right hand of the window that appears, ensure that "No input" is selected from the *Service receives* drop-down list
5. Ensure the *In* drop-down list is showing "Any application"
6. In the second column containing the long list, find "Run AppleScript" and double-click on it
7. This will add the Run AppleScript window on the right
8. Now, **replace** the (* Your script goes here *) bit with your script
9. Save the service using a meaningful name

Now you should be able to run that service from *any* application as described above, that is from the Services list within any Application menu.

Of course, at Step 6 you can select different options depending on what type of script you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your user's **~/Library/Scripts/** folder is arranged so that items in the root of the directory are available in all applications, and **~/Library/Scripts/Applications/** contains folders for application-specific items that are only available when that particular application is active.

A folder for an application can be opened (or created) in the Finder by activating/bringing the desired app to the front and using **Open Scripts Folder > Open (AppName) Scripts Folder** from the Script menu item.

The Script menu can also contain applications and aliases.